# Updating egg files in docker container

Tags: python, docker, egg

After making changes to files in my docker container, I type `python setup.py install --user` to update it. However, it does not update the egg files and I can't see the changes I made on the functions in jupyter notebook. How can I properly update the egg files in the docker container?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Typically you need to rebuild the underlying image and then recreate the container.  You don't generally "make changes to files in my container" since those changes will get lost as soon as the container exits.

Comment: Imagine you have a 10GB container. Rebuilding the image and then recreating the container for each update is nothing but a waste of time. I'm looking for a way to do this without reinstalling the required packages.